# Access variable's value by Prototype in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm suppose to access the value of the variable using defined prototype but I don't know how do I get the value by doing this. I search many examples but not get the proper solution.

For clear understanding here is the example.

```
String.prototype._ = console.log(this);
const a = '10';
a._;
```

This is the simple one, I didn't get the proper value defined in `a`. Your help will appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a getter on the prototype:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "_", {
  get() {
    console.log(this);
  }
});

 "It works"._;  // logs into the console
```

Comment: *[String: 'It works']* It return output like this. But I want only the value.

Comment: @mayur then log `this.valueOf()`